# How to resolve AssertionError for converting string characters to bytes using run length encoding?

Tags: python, encoding

I have a problem to solve but once I submit my solution the result shows an `AssertionError`.
I want to be able to convert my string of characters into a byte format using a technique called run-length encoding - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

I was doing some research on it and found that what I felt done by me was correct but the solution was apparently not correct on the website and I get this: `AssertionError: 'a5b6c4' is not an instance of <class 'bytes'> : compress('') should return bytes`

My code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def compress(raw=str)->bytes: 
    dict=OrderedDict.fromkeys(my_str_as_bytes, 0) 
    for ch in my_str_as_bytes: 
        dict[ch] += 1
    output = '' 
    for key,value in dict.items(): 
        output = output + key + str(value) 
    return output

my_str_as_bytes = "aaaaabbbbbbcccc"
print (bytes(compress(my_str_as_bytes,),encoding='UTF-8'))
```

The result on my IDE was:
`b'a5b6c4'`

I'm not sure of what I did is encoding the string and changing it into a byte or not. Any help would be appreciated.
Few of the links I checked:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/run-length-encoding-in-python

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-length-encoding-python/

Comment: The `assert` is checking that `compress('')` return bytes.  It doesn't, it returns `output` which is a `str`.  Output needs to be encoded before it is returned.

Comment: Can you show how I can do it?

Comment: `return output.encode('ascii')` would do the trick I should think.